# Change file/dir time stamps in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, utilities

Where can I get the touch utility for Windows?

I have tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/touch_win.aspx) one at CodeProject but it did not change directorys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use powershell to do this as well. I have the following function in my $profile

```
function touch([string] $filename)
{
$curTime = Get-Date
$touchFile = get-item $filename
$touchFile.CreationTime = $curTime
$touchFile.LastAccessTime = $curTime
$touchFile.lastWriteTime = $curTime
}
```

Comment: I think that this could be extended to allow the date to be supplied

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command

While most of them suggest getting [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (my bias too) or some other unix utilities,
there is one answer describing a windows method.

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

Another simple solution from the same answer is to get the Cygwin.dll and touch.exe copied  locally in your windows system. It will work better if you want to process directories recursively.

Comment: how does this copy command allow you to change the date time stamp

Comment: The /b treats the file as binary and the +,, tell it to copy the file back to the same place effectively updating the timestamp. But, since you ask, i prefer the Cygwin, touch.exe method.

Comment: but that only allows you to set the timestamp to now

Comment: Ah, you should use the Cygwin method with touch then -- it will be touch -t [[CC]]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss].